# XML parsing ':' in XElement

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, namespaces, xmpp

I am creating `XElement` object on name "stream:stream" but it raises `XMLException` such that
':' cannot be included in a name.

here first stream is a namespace.

Comment: It's a good idea to show what you have already tryied by posting some code. You probably need to create the XName including the namespace. (strings are converted to XNames implicitly)

Comment: Hi rakesh. I have doubts regards how to create a xmpp chat client. This is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781975/xmpp-chat-client-in-windows-phone-7-5 As you crossed the beginning stage in xmpp chat app, Your answer would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to make sure you add the namespace to the document before you start using namespaces in the elements:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You specify namespaces like this:

```
XNamespace streamNs = "some-url-here";
// The + operator here creates an XName
XElement element = new XElement(streamNs + "stream");
```

To make this create an element of "stream:stream" you'd need an `xmlns` attribute for `stream` in some element, e.g.

```
// Add this to an element - either the element in the namespace, or some parent
// element. The document root is a common place to put all namespaces...
XAttribute streamNs = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "stream",
                                     streamNs.NamespaceName);
```