# Matrix xmpp SDK in windows phone mango, want to notify the user for new chat message even if app is running in background

Tags: c#, matrix, xmpp, windows-phone-7.1

I am using the MatriX xmpp library for chatting purposes. It works fine when my application is running in foreground, however I want to notify the user about a new chat message even if my application is in background. Is this possible? As per the link below it may be possible, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
http://www.ag-software.de/2011/05/25/windows-phone-mango/
```

Please let me know if you have a solution to this question.

Comment: this was already discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781975/xmpp-chat-client-in-windows-phone-7-5/9783006#9783006